# Blender 2.8 - weathering effects

Tags: materials

Is there an efficient way to add a weathering effect to an object?  By weathering, I am thinking of an overlaid thin layer of mottled grime on a sign or a car, maybe a little rust here or there.

Comment: How much does the non-trial version cost?

Comment: @whatamesh Is there a way to do what I want without Substance Painter?  I have nothing to do with that product...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I settled on was relatively simple:  because the underlying object was a rectangle, I created a plane of the same dimensions and superimposed it on top; loaded a black and white image for texture and then adjusted the transparency.  It can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146515/blender-2-8-simple-approach-to-overlaying-dirt).

Answer (score 1):

There are many video-tutorials for this topic on Youtube and (answered) questions here in BSE. To get you started I selected some of them for you:

[How to Make Rust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37oBqhjDtBI)

[Quickly Add Dirt to Crevices](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX4dkwU1pyQ)

[Using Ambient Occlusion to add Grunge](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrb716STIlw)

[Need to make (node setup) of realistic dirt/ grime/grunge on top of image texture of ceramic tiles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/need-to-make-node-setup-of-realistic-dirt-grime-grunge-on-top-of-image-textur)