# Dirty Pool Texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

Hi I made a 3D model of the image below and gave it a texture.
How should I Dirty my model's textured image?
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to make (node setup) of realistic dirt/ grime/grunge on top of image texture of ceramic tiles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34455/need-to-make-node-setup-of-realistic-dirt-grime-grunge-on-top-of-image-textur)